# Can I award a bounty to my old question?

Tags: support, bug, bounties

[Take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491265/output-with-thread-class-and-runnable-interface). I can't award a bounty to this question. But I need an answer to this question. Is it possible to award a bounty to questions ?

Note: I'm not fully familiar with the bounty system.

Comment: You need at least 75 reputation before you can start a bounty. You only have 53.

Comment: oh yes. I am confused. sorry. Last week bounty I gained Bounties privilege. I got it now. thanks.

Comment: Next time think twice before starting bounty on other questions... rep is precious. :)

Comment: ok sure buddy. Thanks @ShadowWizard